# Access all user registries with Remote Registry Service

Tags: windows, powershell, registry, remote-registry

I'm currently working on a PowerShell tool that reads from the registry remotely via the Remote Registry Service. When a user is logged in, the data I'm reading from is located in `HKCU\Software\`. Obviously, when a computer has multiple user accounts, HKCU will not accurately reflect all users. Is there a dynamic way where I can loop through all users on a computer and access their registries?

Currently I'm doing the following in PowerShell:

```
$KeyType = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::CurrentUser
$BaseRegKey = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey($KeyType, $RemoteComputer)
$SoftwareKey = $BaseRegKey.OpenSubKey($SoftwarePathEnding)
```

How would I be able to use similar code to loop through all users to get the right data I'm looking for?

Sorry if this isn't explained too well and if I'd need to provide some clarification.

Comment: What's your end goal? This may be better accomplished with group policy.

Answer (score 4):

`HKCU` is a shortcut to `HKU\<User-SID>`, where the `ntuser.dat` from the user's profile is loaded at login. To get access to every user's registry branch you need to load each user's `ntuser.dat` first, e.g. by running `reg load` on the remote host via `Invoke-Command`.

```
Invoke-Command -Computer 'hostname' -ScriptBlock {
    & reg load 'HKU\someuser' 'C:\Users\someuser\ntuser.dat'
}
```

Don't forget to `reg unload` the file after you're done.

Comment: Right on, I like that answer. I was hoping to go with something without having to run commands on the remote host, but this makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: To clarify 'shortcut', `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` is a predefined key handle that the API automatically maps to a handle for "\Registry\User\<User SID>" for the current process. It's not obviously meaningful to use this handle with a remote registry. `HKEY_USERS` is another predefined handle, which gets mapped either to a handle for the local "\Registry\User" or an RPC handle for this key on a remote system. Using predefined handles simplifies the API for current-user and remote access. IMO, the way the names of predefined handles get used in path strings obfuscates that it's a handle-relative path.